# MS Word: how to stop changing formatting of text based on style?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a permanent problem of auto-changing alignment (from the 'right' to the 'left') of bulleted list, for which I created style2, based on another one created style1.

For all styles I set align to 'left' or 'justify'. Though, from time to time, when I made some changes to style1 (nothing with aligning), I notice lists with style2 are aligned to the right!

Maybe I need to clean up style formatting somehow, but can't figure it out.

I feel like my explanations sounds very hard, but that's very annoying, and if someone needs more clarifications to solve this problem I'll be greatful.

Comment: May be a screenshot will help to make everything clearer

Comment: @fernando.reyes Thanks for your comment, though I can't imagine which screenshot could explain something. My problem was that somehow custom style based on another custom style was auto correcting alignment to 'right'. For now I just created new style based on default.